# How to show subsequence converges and find its limit??

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> I have two subsequences $\langle x_{2k}\rangle \in (0,1)$ for all $k$ and $\langle x_{2k-1}\rangle \in (1,2)$ for all $k$
>
> How do I show each subsequence converges, and identify its limit??

My knowledge is that there is a definition that states: the sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$ converges to limit $L$ if every $\varepsilon > 0$ for some $N \in\mathbb N$ so that
$$
|x_n-L|<\varepsilon
$$
for every $n>N$

then I think it should somehow looks like 
$$
|x_{2k}-L|<\epsilon
$$
how could i progress further and find its limit point at some stage??

Comment: Note that proper notation is $\langle x_{2k}\rangle$, not <$x_{2k}$>. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: Is $\langle x_n \rangle$ a convergent sequence? Then the subsequences converge to the same limit that $\langle x_n \rangle$ converges to.

Comment: @AdamFrancey I have a function $f(x)=1-x^2$, so do i plug this function into where $x_n$ is?

Comment: Can you post the full problem you have? I have no idea where you got $f$ from, and how it relates to the sequences in your post.

Comment: And if your subsequences aren't from a convergent sequence $\langle x_n \rangle$, then there is no guarantee that they converge.

Comment: In your other question it said $x_n \in (0,1)$ for all $n$. So how did your $x_{2k-1} \in (1,2)$ comes from?

Comment: I made that up because i thought i could solve this question without stating all that other questions, because, in fact, $x_{2k} \in (p_0,1)$ is the right answer. but then i have to explain what $p_0$ is and so on.. so i made that number up and I wanted to solve the actual problem by myself

Comment: Then without any extra assumption the sequence might not converge, as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated,
the subsequences do not
have to converge.

For example,
$x_{2k}
=\frac12+\frac14 (-1)^k
$
and
$x_{2k+1}
=\frac32+\frac14 (-1)^k
$.